# Delete program core file in bash script

Tags: bash, core-file

I'm trying to delete the core file generated from when my program suddenly crashes.

For that i use this piece of code:

```
find . -name 'core' -delete
```

My question is: Is this a correct way of doing it ? Is there a better and more efficient way?

Comment: Are you sure that the developer wants you to do this?  Better to fix the program.  core dumps can be a useful diagnostic aid.  BTW, on some platforms (e.g. Linux) core dumps can have the PID appended to their name (configurable), so `'core*'` might be more appropriate.

Comment: yeah, this is for a college project, so it is for learning purposes @cdarke. Anyway is this  an acceptable solution ?

Comment: Remember that `find` recurses through sub-directories, if that's what you want it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed want to delete those core file, you can use:

```
find . -name "core*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Note: [**including semicolon**]

Comment: Can you explain what that does ?

Comment: `find . -name "core*"`:   means  find all files those name beginning with "core".
`-exec rm -f`: `  means execute `rm -f` command. `rm-f` command means delete without confirm. `{} \;` means store the find results to here to be feed to `rm -f` command.

Comment: when i run the command `find . -name 'core*' -exec rm -f {}\ ` i get his error: `find: missing argument to -exec `

Comment: Did you missed the semicolon in the end? I update the answer to reflect this. And there is a space between `}` and `\`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is hard (if not impossible at all) to come up with a "perfect solution" since the names are core files are customizable.

In linux, /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern determines the name of core files. Therefore, you should check that to decide the pattern to be used in your "find" command.